# To retrieve the contents of .doc files?

Tags: blackberry

I am working as a Software developer for Mobile Applications. I am developing an application in which i want to retrieve the contents of the .doc files that arrive on the Blackberry mobile as an Email Attachment Part. Whenever i am retrieving the contents of the .txt files, the code written for the mobile is retrieving the accurate contents but in case of .doc files, it is displaying a lot of junk material in the header and footer of the actual contents.

So, my problem is that how can i get rid of this additional junk material as i want to retrieve only the actual contents of the .doc files. Please reply

Thanks

Comment: What format are you actually trying to open? .txt? .doc? And what code do you currently use? A third-party lib? Your own code? Are you using any converter?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the specifications of the doc-Format from [Microsoft](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F0%2FB%2FE%2F0BE8BDD7-E5E8-422A-ABFD-4342ED7AD886%2FWord97-2007BinaryFileFormat(doc)Specification.pdf&rct=j&q=DOC+specification&ei=rPfeSuasN9fMjAfU-u1t&usg=AFQjCNGBvA85ycIxc055rz6G4kV95-HFwg). Though, I don't know if they're complete or even useful. Another guess would be to have a look at Projects which have implemented it, like OpenOffice.org.

Bobby